# Adding discount for whole cart

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, coupon

I would like to create a coupon with following conditions:
 - There are special products for which the coupon is valid 
 - For the first article, you get 10%
 - If you buy the second article you get additionally 5% on the whole cart
 - And if you buy a third article or more you get additionally 5% on the cart, so the maximum discount is 20%
 - For this, the quantity of the article doesn't matter

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this point you can use this scenario:

Rule 1

Conditions - if qty of articles = 1

Discount - 10%

Rule 2

Conditions - if qty of articles = 2

Discount = 15%

Rule 3

Conditions - if qty of articles = 3

Discount = 20%

You do not need to create any specify rules, just play with settings

Comment: thanks, but not exactly what I need. I have in my shop around 100 products. These special conditions are only for 15 special products. But if somebody buys one of the 15 products and one of the other 85, then the discount should only applied on the product out of the 15 products. Additionally it doesn't matter if you buy 1 oder 2 of this product: